# Why are the tension force and the gravitational forces not equal and opposite?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram, string

Solving a complex system with two masses: In the picture below, we see an Atwood machine. In this apparatus, m1 starts out from rest 1.5m above the ground. The mass of m1 is 3kg and m2 is 2kg. m2 is initially held on the ground, but then is let go.

• Draw force diagrams for each box.
• Find the work done on the boxes    by all the forces on all boxes. Compare values and discuss using    Newton’s third law.

[image: Atwood Machine Setup]

I have done all of the work to find acceleration, tension force, and gravitational force on both boxes, but I am confused as to why the tension force and gravitational force for each box are not equal and opposite to their gravitational forces.
Here is my work:
F = ma
m1g - T = m1a
T - m2g = m2a
Gives: m1g - m2g = a(m1 + m2)
a = (m1g - m2g)/(m1 + m2)
a = (3 kg)(9.80 m/s^2) - (2 kg)(9.80 m/s^2)/(3 kg + 2 kg)
a = 1.96 m/s^2
Then to find tension (one string so tension would be the same for both boxes so I only used one equation):
m1g - T = m1a
T = m1a - m1g
T = (3 kg)(1.96 m/s^2) - (3 kg)(9.80 m/s^2)
T = 23.52 N

Then for gravitational forces:
m1: (3 kg)(9.80 m/s^2) = 29.4 N
m2:(2 kg)(9.80 m/s^2) = 19.6 N

I understand why the gravitational forces are different from one another, but because the tension force on each mass is the same, this violates Newton's 3rd law (every action has an equal and opposite reaction). The gravitational force of m1 does not equal 23.52 N and neither does the gravitational force of m2. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Tension and gravity are not an action-reaction pair.**

There's nothing that dictates tension must be equal and opposite to gravity. If they were, the forces would balance perfectly, and none of the masses would move. But it's clear that the heavier mass connected to a pulley should descend to the floor - the tension on the rope holding it up is *insufficient* to counteract gravity. Conversely, on the other end of the rope, the lighter mass ascends, because the tension pulling upward is *greater* than the force of gravity pulling downward. We can see from everyday experience that tension isn't necessarily equal and opposite to gravity. The force of gravity is dictated by the object's mass and position in a gravitational field, while the force of gravity is dictated by how hard you pull on the rope - those physical quantities have no fixed relationship in an arbitrary scenario.

The confusion arises in considering tension and gravity as an always-equal, always-opposite pair of forces, which is not the case. Tension is effectively its own reaction force - the force pulling on M1 is exactly equal and opposite to the force pulling on M2. Gravity also requires that two objects are pulling *on each other*, which is where the equal and opposite pair comes in - the earth pulls M1 downward exactly as hard as M1 pulls the earth upward, and the same is true for M2.

Answer (score 0):

> The gravitational force of m1 does not equal 23.52 N and neither does the gravitational force of m2. Am I doing something wrong?

Yes, you are. You have misunderstood the Newton's third law like many students do in their early classes.

This law says that the force applied by a body $A$ on a body $B$ is equal and opposite to the force applied by $B$ on $A$. The gravitational force is applied by the earth on the two masses and thus the two masses apply same gravitational force on the earth.
These forms an action - reaction pair.

While the rope applies tension on both the blocks and thus both the blocks apply same tension force on the rope. This also forms an action - reaction pair.

Your argument that weight should be equal to tension using Newton's third law has no sense at all.

Hope it helps .